# sort json arrays inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple json arrays inside an array. I need to sort the json arrays in ascending order by name first and item.

```
var result = [[{"name":"james","item":"car"....],[{"name":"adrian","item":"car"....}],[{"name":"adrian","item":"truck"...}]]

 result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name).localeCompare(b.name)  ||  (a.item).localeCompare(b.item);
});

Output desired: [ [{"name":"adrian","item":"car"}],[{"name":"adrian","item":"truck"}],[{"name":"james","item":"car"}] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments to `sort` function is an array. Please post complete sample to give you more accurate result. With the above sample below code will work.

```
        var result = [[{ "name": "james", "item": "car" }], [{ "name": "adrian", "item": "car" }], [{ "name": "adrian", "item": "truck" }]]

        result.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name) || a[0].item.localeCompare(b[0].item);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you were close. Since it's arrays in array, use that

```
var result = [[{"name":"james","item":"car"}],[{"name":"adrian","item":"car"}],[{"name":"adrian","item":"truck"}]];

 result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a[0].name).localeCompare(b[0].name)  ||  (a[0].item).localeCompare(b[0].item);
});
```

And test result with :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

=>

```
[[{"name":"adrian","item":"car"}],[{"name":"adrian","item":"truck"}],[{"name":"james","item":"car"}]]
```